# Creating a slide out draw of buttons in android?

Tags: android, button, slider

In an app i saw , there where 5 tabs at the bottom , when the last tab is pressed is opens a 
'vertical slide out draw ' (for lack of better words) in the right corner of the screen from 
bottom moving up.  Is there any pre built view for such an action.

or  can some one suggest how this can be acomplished.
[image]

As i dont have a screen shot here is a simple sketch. The 3 buttons slide out when tab 5 is pressed.

Comment: can you post image or something of what you saw and what you want

Comment: @Karan Mer i just added a simple sketch of what i saw.